# Android : read sqlite database from http request

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want to make an auto update database (the database only) for my app, 
as far i understand,

1. making some change data in my database and update `date value` in database
2. put it in server (mydatabase.db -->> this is sqlite database)
3. then select `date value` mydatabase.db from android devices and compare with select `date value`  mydatabase.db from new updated database from server
4. if `date value` from devices different from server then download a new database update.

can i do that ? or its any other way to do something like that ?
i want to make my app can update my local sqlite database app.

Comment: You should probably read a little more on client-server architecture so you have a head start

Comment: thanks, i'm reading on it right now.